# how to iterate a result of jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

I want to iterate a result of query selector.

Html code

```
<nav id="navigation">
        <a href="#" tabindex="1" class="active_nav">nav1</a>
        <a href="#" tabindex="2">nav2</a>
        <a href="#"tabindex="3">nav3</a>
</nav>
```

when I use javascript

```
alert($("#navigation >a")[0]);
```

the result is the tag `a` href attribute
I don't know why.

Comment: what output you want ?

Comment: You can use `.each` http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @TusharGupta I want to get the first DOM object but not the attribute of the first object

Comment: check my answer i have iterated through all the a tags

Comment: @TusharGupta why `$("#navigation >a")[0];` returns href attribute of the first tag not the 1st dom object

Comment: You need to specify which a tag you want. In this case, you want the first one so `$("#navigation > a:eq(0)")[0]`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `$.each`

```
$("#navigation > a").each(function() {

     console.log(this.href)
});
```

---

```
$('#navigation > a')[0]
      ^              ^---- Selects the 1st dom object from the jQuery object
      |                    that is nothing but the index of the element among 
      |                    the list of elements
      |-------  Gives you children of nav(3 anchor tags in this case)  which is a
                jQuery object that contains the list of matched elements
```

Comment: why the `$("#navigation >a")[0];` returns the href attribute of the first tag not the 1st dom object

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery built-in `each()` for this iteration like this:

```
$("#navigation>a").each(function(index){
    console.log("I am " + index + "th element.");
    //and you can access this element by $(this)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate all `<a>` tags, you can use each function

```
$('#navigation >a').each(function() { 
    alert(this.href);
});
```

and if you only want to get the first `<a>` tag then use .eq()

```
alert($('#navigation >a').eq(0).attr('href');
```

Comment: For first `<a>` there is a simpler way: `$('#navigation >a:first')`

Comment: but I want to know why the `$("#navigation >a")[0];` returns the href attribute of the first tag...

Comment: $("#navigation >a")[0] returns the DOM element.  Don't use alert() to see what it returns as it only displays the href attribute.  Try to use inspect element in Chrome or use firebug for firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Use `first()` like this:

```
var element = $("#navigation>a").first();
console.log(element);
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: but I want to iterate the whole set not only the first one. and I want to know why the `$("#navigation >a")[0];` returns the href attribute of the first tag.

Comment: Your query: "I want to get the first DOM object but not the attribute of the first object"

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery, when you use index like `[0]`, it means you are access the DOM element. That is why

```
$("#navigation >a")[0]
```

returns `<a>` tag.

In order to iterate a jQuery selector result, use each

```
$("#navigation >a").each(function(index, elem){
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
console.log($("#navigation >a"))
```

instead, so you can see all the results in the console ( cmd + alt + i in chrome)